# My webapp shows 502 Bad Gateway after running Kill commands

Tags: reactjs, nginx, amazon-ec2, vite

I have taken over a webapp that I had a developer create a prototype for. I have very limited knowledge in coding but figured I could do it with my web design experience and GPT and I've been wrong.

The developer left the site off with multiple https and http issues. The site was supposed to be working on https but the dev made files load in http. I've been trying to change that.

I went into three files, two network.ts files and a socket.js file where the code showed http, GPT said to change these to https then run a kill -9 commmand on the PID's, which I did and then yarn dev to restart.

Ever since then, my site has shown 502 Bad Gateway, even though I changed the files back to http.

GPT keeps telling me to go into different files and mess around with port numbers and IP's, but all these files were working just fine before the kill commands, and when I do follow its advice, it doesnt work and it just goes in circles repeating the same things that didn't work previously.

Its an aws ec2 instance running on nginx, with vite, react, and ts.

I'm at my wits end here. How do I get my site back up and running and then have the files load https?

Everything from above.